# Sound manager - Libgdx Android

Tags: libgdx

Some android devices has differente volume controls. One for calls, one for messages and one for applications.

In this devices, My game affects all 3 volumes controls.

I’m using a very basic code:

```
Music music;
music = bb.assets.get("sounds/breaking_stuff.mp3", Music.class);
music.play();
music.setLooping(true);
music.setVolume(0.5f);
```

I have to do some special trative for these devices?
I would like these cases, only the volume of the application was changed.

How to do that?

Comment: LibGDX is set up to set the Android volume control stream to the music stream, and to play audio on that stream. Have you done anything out of the ordinary in setting up your launcher activity? Which stream gets modified by the volume controls while your game is open?

Comment: There's nothing special, just like put up, do not do anything beyond that. I make no treatment beyond this code. This happened on a device that has 3 controls independent volume.

Comment: I talked to the user who reported the problem, and in fact, the problem is affecting 3 volumes of the device when it should only change the volume of applications. I edited the post with this information.